# Using SAML security in JAXWS web serives

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saml, saml-2.0

I am currently using Basic HTTP Authentication yo my SOAP web services.

I want to use SAML security token for authentication and authorization.

Can some share some pointers for learning.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using (Java, apparently, but which STS)? What have you tried?

Comment: This blog seems to be a good starting point for development : http://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/opensaml-with-web-services

Comment: This blog no longer exists.